# Mongoose Filter based on Dynamic Date Key with value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created an employee attendance application where attendances are logged and stored in a database. I have tried to obtain a count of all date-field with the value of `"Present"`. Data are stored in the database like so :

```
"attendances": { <YYYY-MM-DD>: "value" } pair 
// The values being "Absent" or "Present" whatever the case may be.
```

The problem is, I get a value of `0` whenever I try to count all the entries with `"attendances": {"2019-08-28": "Present"}`.

Can anyone help me find out what am doing wrong?

//Schema

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const employeeSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  department: String,
  origin: String,
  employDate: String,
  attendances: Object
});
module.exports= Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema);
```

route.js

```
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  Employee.collection.countDocuments({"attendances.date":"present"},(err,data)=>{
    if(err){
      res.status(500)
      res.send(err)
    }else{
      res.status(200)
      res.json(data)
    }
  })

})
```

//Data stored in MongoDB

```
  {
        "_id": "5d6565236574b1162c349d8f",
        "name": "Benjamin Hall",
        "department": "IT",
        "origin": "Texas",
        "employDate": "2019-08-27",
        "__v": 0,
        "attendances": {
            "2019-08-28": "Sick"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d6367ee5b78d30c74be90e6",
        "name": "Joshua Jaccob",
        "department": "Marketing",
        "origin": "new york",
        "employDate": "2019-08-26",
        "__v": 0,
        "attendances": {
            "2019-08-26": "Present",
            "2019-08-27": "Sick"
        }
    },
```

Comment: You are trying to count `attendence.date` which is undefined in database. Quick fix would be `Wages.collection.countDocuments({"attendances": { "2019-08-26": "present"}}, ...rest of the code`

Comment: Also, the search is case sensitive, you must put the exact value of the string in search.

> **Wages.collection.countDocuments({"attendances": { "2019-08-26": "Present"}}**

Comment: thanks for your response. I just tried your solution now `Wages.collection.countDocuments({"attendances": { "2019-08-26": "present"}},` but am still getting a count of ''0'' i.e Zero

Comment: @A.Todkar, thanks for pointing out the case-sensitive nature of search. I was actually using lowercase in my code, However, after changing "present" to upperCase "Present", it still returns a count of ZERO

Answer (score 1):

Since the dynamic date is part of an embedded document, to query on that field with a regex expression (for case insensitive search) you essentially need to use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents) `{ "attendance.2019-08-28": /present/i }`, constructed using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) as:

```
const date = "2019-08-28" // dynamic date
const query = {
    ["attendances." + date]: /present/i // computed property name
}

Employee.countDocuments(query, (err, data) => {
    if (err){
        res.status(500).send(err)
    } else{
        res.status(200).json(data)
    }
})
```

Note, [`countDocuments()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments) function can be accessed directly on the Mongoose model.

---

For a date range query, say for example you want to return the count of attendances that were present for the last 30 days, you would need
to query with the aggregation framework which exposes operators like [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to give you the count.

The above operators allow you to convert the attendances document into an array of key value pairs with [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) which you can then filter based on the past 30 days criteria as well as the "present" value using [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/). To get the count, use the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator on the filtered array.

As an illustration, applying [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) on the document

```
{
    "2019-08-26": "Present",
    "2019-08-27": "Sick"
}
```

returns

```
[
    { "k": "2019-08-26", "v": "Present" },
    { "k": "2019-08-27", "v": "Sick" }
]
```

To filter on the past n days you will need to first create a list of dates in that range i.e.

```
[
    "2019-08-27",
    "2019-08-26",
    "2019-08-25",
    ...
]
```

which can be done in JavaScript as

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}


const listDatesForThePastDays = n => (
    Array(n)
        .fill(new Date())
        .map((today, i) => today - 8.64e7 * i)
        .map(formatDate)
)
```

This list can be used in the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) as

```
{ "$filter": {
    "input": { "$objectToArray": "$attendances" },
    "cond": {
        "$and": [
            { "$in": ["$$this.k", listDatesForThePastDays(30)] },
            { "$eq": ["$$this.v", "Present"] }
        ]
    }
} }
```

And apply the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator to get the count:

```
{ "$size": {
    "$filter": {
        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$attendances" },
        "cond": {
            "$and": [
                { "$in": ["$$this.k", listDatesForThePastDays(30)] },
                { "$eq": ["$$this.v", "Present"] }
            ]
        }
    }
} }
```

Your overall query will look like

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}


const listDatesForThePastDays = n => (
    Array(n)
        .fill(new Date())
        .map((today, i) => today - 8.64e7 * i)
        .map(formatDate)
)

Employee.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": { 
        "numberofPresentAttendances": { 
            "$size": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": { "$objectToArray": "$attendances" },
                    "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$in": ["$$this.k", listDatesForThePastDays(30)] },
                            { "$eq": ["$$this.v", "Present"] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } }
]).exec().
  .then(results => {
      console.log(results);
      // results will be an array of employee documents with an extra field numberofPresentAttendances
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```

---

To get the count for all employees then you need to group all the documents as

```
Employee.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null,
        "totalPresent": {
            "$sum": { 
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$attendances" },
                        "cond": {
                            "$and": [
                                { "$in": ["$$this.k", listDatesForThePastDays(30)] },
                                { "$eq": ["$$this.v", "Present"] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    } }
]).exec()
.then(results => {
    console.log(results);
    // results will be an array of employee documents with an extra field numberofPresentAttendances
})
.catch(console.error)
```

Comment: @chridam---I just tried your solution,(Making use of Postman) and I get status 200K, but the count is still ZERO

Comment: @Chrisdam thanks for your latest edit, Everything is very clear now. I appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find by property in embedded document you have to use dot notation

this will not work, because you are asking mongoo to find the document which have attendances object equal the same given object.

```
{ "attendances": {"2019-08-26": "Present"}}
```

this will work only if attendances object in your database contains only

```
{ "attendances": {"2019-08-26": "Present"}}
```

that's mean that you asking mongoo if the stored object is equal the given object and it will return false

```
 { "attendances": {"2019-08-26": "Present" , "2019-08-27": "Sick"}} ==  { "attendances": {"2019-08-26": "Present"}}
```

to do this you have to use dot notation

```
 Employee.collection.countDocuments({"attendances.2019-08-26":"Present"},(err,data)=>{
    if(err){
      res.status(500)
      res.send(err)
    }else{
      res.status(200)
      res.json(data)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Finally.. it works!  it returns a value" >0", and your explanation is on point also. Just want to ask to clarify an additional query(if you don't mind,). What if I wanted all attendances with "present" let's say for the last 30 days...can you give me a clue what to do? if you choose to pass, thanks anyway!

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this with mongo queries, because attendace key is a string not a date to check if it greater than X or less thean Y, so You have to retrieve all data which have present, then filter this data by constructing new date and check if it gt other date or not, there is another option I prefer, you can change your schema to be attendances array of embedded docs `{ day: Date, status: string }` that's will be more flexible than object type, if you did that you can search by attendance day and count monthly attendance per employee and do many things obj can't do

Comment: thanks for the tip, but truthfully though, my challenge will be retrieving all data that has "present".... anyway, I will give it a try!